# NSURL of an image from UIImagePicker

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an image from my phone to my `Amazon S3` bucket:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)
{
    var uploadReq = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
    uploadReq.bucket = "bucketname";
    uploadReq.key = "testimage.png"
    uploadReq.body = image; //This line needs an NSURL
}
```

How can I get the NSURL of the image the user selected from a `UIImagePickerController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Zhengjie's answer might work. I found a more simple way to go about it:

```
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("imagetoupload"))
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    data.writeToURL(fileURL!, atomically: true)
    uploadReq.body = fileURL
```

Answer (score 0):

First U should save the Image to Document Directory. then Post the URL.
U can do like this :

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)  // get the data
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.UserDomainMask,true) as! [String]
let path = paths[0]
let fileName = "testimage.png"
let filePath = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)  // get the file url to save 

var error:NSError?
if !data.writeToFile(photoPath, options: .DataWritingAtomic, error: &error) {// save the data
  logger.error("Error write file: \(error)")
}

upload.body = NSURL(string: filePath)  // used url to post to server
}
```